# java delimeter replacement for new line

Tags: android, split, substring, csv

Here is the scenario one input

```
String in = "<ENTER>title=Java-Samples<ENTER>" + 
                        "<ENTER>author=Emiley J<ENTER>" + 
                        "<ENTER>publisher=java-samples.com<ENTER>" + 
                        "<ENTER>copyright=2007<ENTER>" +
                        "<ENTER>cool beans<ENTER>";
```

processs

```
    in=in.substring(in.indexOf("<ENTER>")+7,in.lastIndexOf("<ENTER>"));
    String[] mSplitted= in.replaceAll("<ENTER><ENTER>", "<ENTER>").split("<ENTER>");
    String mFinal="";

    for(int i=0;i<mSplitted.length;i++)
    {
       System.out.println("values: "+mSplitted[i]);
       mFinal= mFinal+ mSplitted[i];
    }
    System.out.println(mFinal);
```

output is

title=Java-Samplesauthor=Emiley Jpublisher=java-samples.comcopyright=2007cool beans

Senario 2

input

```
        String in = "What is the output of: <ENTER><ENTER>echo 6 % 4;";
```

processes

```
    in=in.substring(in.indexOf("<ENTER>")+7,in.lastIndexOf("<ENTER>"));
    String[] mSplitted= in.replaceAll("<ENTER><ENTER>", "<ENTER>").split("<ENTER>");
    String mFinal="";

    for(int i=0;i<mSplitted.length;i++)
    {
      // System.out.println("values: "+mSplitted[i]);
       mFinal= mFinal+ mSplitted[i];
    }
    System.out.println(mFinal);
```

Output
nothing

I want the output to add a new line when  is used

Comment: If it _works fine_ then what is your question about?

Comment: A bit, but not much... Why don't you show us the scenario that works, whats the input and the output; then show us the scenario that doesn't work, the input, the current output, and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not 100% on your question but how about this:

```
String mFinal = in.replaceAll("<ENTER><ENTER>", "\n").replaceAll("<ENTER>", "");
```

Comment: i checked some further data and i need todo something with single <ENTER> as well

Comment: The code I posted simply removes any single `<ENTER>` expressions, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: i fixed it sam thanks so much. Your explanation was very detailed and clear to understand

Comment: can i include more then one delimeter I have <COMMA> as well.

Comment: You can execute `replaceAll()` on as many deliminators as you please.

Comment: is there a condition where i can choose one or more deliemters at the same time or choose one or the other

Comment: You can look into [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) but it seems simpler to use a separate `replaceAll()` for your current set of deliminators.  `String mFinal = in.replaceAll("<ENTER><ENTER>", "\n").replaceAll("<ENTER>", "").replaceAll("<COMMA>", ",");`

Comment: String[] mSplitted= in.replaceAll("<ENTER>", "\n").split("<ENTER>"); i realized that i want to add multiple replace All to the string array but it isn't working

Comment: fantastic answer. I have used your advise in a live project.